# Urban myth but for non-myths

Tags: single-word-requests

What's some slang for "common public belief" that doesn't have any implications about the truthfulness of the belief?

Similar to "common sense", but I'm looking for a phrase that has more "urban myth" flavour. Not some rationale intrinsic to every human (as common sense might imply), but more so spread by word of mouth or such around the population and established collectively. The word should have the same feeling as "broscience", but not be about the gym specifically.

Street-smarts or street wisdom come to mind, but I haven't found them to be established terms for this. Street-smarts especially seems to have a different meaning, about dealing with danger.

> _____ is that being cold weakens your immune system and makes you more susceptible to catching illness

> _____ would see you running the other way as soon as ..., but actually....

Answer (score 2):

**Conventional wisdom** is perhaps the best phrase. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conventional%20wisdom) defines it as "the generally accepted belief, opinion, judgment, or prediction about a particular matter" with the example "Conventional wisdom in Hollywood says that a movie can't succeed unless it stars a famous actor or actress." It has a sense of being what is generally or universally believed, and generally with a certain element of truth, although perhaps without scientific rigor or formal proof.

There are many phrases such as folk wisdom, old wives tales, urban myths, all of which more or less imply something is untrue or at minimum believed for little or no reason. But the OP asks for a term "that doesn't have any implications about the truthfulness of the belief".

Comment: I would agree that this is the only answer that satisfies that criterion.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged 'single word' but asks for a phrase. [Farlex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Old+wive%27s+tale) has

> **old wives' tale**
> a belief, usually superstitious or erroneous, passed on by word of mouth as a piece of traditional wisdom

So you can say

> An old wives' tale is that being cold weakens your immune system and makes you more susceptible to catching illness.

Comment: This implies something which is untrue, as the definition you quote says.

Comment: @StuartF it doesn't have to be false. Farlex says 'usually' and also "a bit of lore passed on by word of mouth".

Answer (score 0):

**folk wisdom** (n.)

> Wisdom or beliefs associated with or traditional to the ordinary
> people of a country
>
> *Folk wisdom recognizes that to forgive is divine.*
>
> *A leopard's spots are fixed for life, according to folk wisdom, but despite the saying, people do change.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/folk-wisdom)

> The body of knowledge and experience that originates from the beliefs
> and opinions of ordinary people.
>
> *Folk wisdom has ascribed the problem to children sleeping too deeply.*
>
> *The wisdom of the people—folk wisdom, for example—has amassed a great
> wealth of empirical discovery connected with healing.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/folk_wisdom)

> [C. L. Dadhich; *Management Through Folk Wisdom*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Management_Through_Folk_Wisdom/lQ0mAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)

> [C. Voelke and R. Feldman (eds.); A World Treasury of Folk Wisdom](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_World_Treasury_of_Folk_Wisdom/hI2rGAAACAAJ?hl=en)